# how to solve this error when run latex in R?

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex

I'm trying to generate some plots in latex using R, here is the code:

```
msaPrettyPrint(seq_mapped, output="pdf", showNames="none",
               showLogo="none", askForOverwrite=FALSE, verbose=FALSE)
```

and the error:

```
Error in texi2dvi(texfile, quiet = !verbose, pdf = identical(output, "pdf"),  : 
  unable to run pdflatex on 'seq_mapped.tex'
LaTeX errors:
! Paragraph ended before \inf@@get was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.25 ...e}{/tmp/RtmppWEuqI/seq108d544be5486.fasta}
                                                  
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\msfline ->\par &
                  & & & @
l.25 ...e}{/tmp/RtmppWEuqI/seq108d544be5486.fasta}
                                                  
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\msfline ->\par & &
                    & & @
l.25 ...e}{/tmp/RtmppWEuqI/seq108d544be5486.fasta}
                                                  
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\msfline ->\par & & &
                      & @
l.25 ...e}{/tmp/RtmppWEuqI/seq108d544be5486.fasta}
                                                  
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\msfline ->\par & & & &
                        @
l.25 ...e}{/tmp/RtmppWEuqI/seq108d544be5486.fasta}
```

I've also tried:

```
msaPrettyPrint(seq_mapped, output="tex", showNames="none",
               showLogo="none", askForOverwrite=FALSE, verbose=FALSE)
tools::texi2pdf("seq_mapped.tex", clean=TRUE)
```

but still have an error

```
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'seq_mappedt.tex' failed.
LaTeX errors:
! LaTeX Error: File `texshade.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.4 ^^M
       
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

However, the `texshade.sty` is installed:

```
system.file("tex", "texshade.sty", package="msa")
[1] ".../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/msa/tex/texshade.sty"
```

Any ideas?
FYI: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS focal

Thanks

Comment: The location of the sty file seems not exactly like a standard location. Can you run `kpsewhich texshade.sty` to check if latex can find it?

Comment: I do not have any output

Comment: ok, that means tex can't find it. How did you install your tex distribution? Are you using an ubuntu package?

Comment: using this `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` - `sudo apt-get install texmaker`

Comment: Can you try `tlmgr install texshade`? (maybe with sudo)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, it seems to be installed now, but I still have this error: 
`Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'seq_mapped.tex' failed.`

Comment: I had similar issues with using the `texshade` package directly with TeXlive 2021. The output seemed to emit similar macro errors. Trying older versions of TeXlive seemed to work for the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this thread accicentally and I am aware that it 11 months old. However, just in case that it might be of help to somebody, I dare to reply...

Well, let's first start with the second question: You use `msaPrettyPrint()` to write a `.tex` file and then you call `texi2dvi()`. However, you do not supply `texi2dvi()` with the information where `texshade.sty` is. This must be done, since `texshade.sty` is stored within the msa package's folder, and not in the standard folders where LaTeX looks for input files. Long story short - you should do this:

```
tools::texi2pdf("seq_mapped.tex", texinputs=system.file("tex", package="msa"),clean=TRUE)
```

If you do that with the same input data as in the first question, I suppose that the same problem would also arise. In order to answer that in a more qualified way, I would need to try myself with the original files? Are you able to put together a minimal example exhibiting this problem and send it to me by e-mail? ([msa@bioinf.jku.at](https://mailto:msa@bioinf.jku.at))